# Trying to get Featured image from wordpress Databsee tables using limit

Tags: database, wordpress

Where is the featured image link stored in the WordPress Database? I searched in the wp_postmetatable but I cannot find out the exact post_id and links.

Is this correct? Could anyone please explain to me how it works?

I need a query to select featured images from databse

Comment: The WP database is not that straightforward. Can you not use the built-in WP functions for getting the image? That's what they are there for!

Comment: using this query